# Running `pip` in the Google Cloud Shell causes ImportError

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-platform

When I create a new project in Google Cloud Console and just try to run

```
pip
```

I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/sguergachi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Reinstalling doesn't seem to be an option for google cloud as it would for local environment.

Comment: How about `easy_install`?

Comment: @cricket_007 get another error that also ends in `ImportError: No module named packaging.version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be able to do anything in `pip` on GCP you need to run as `sudo`.

```
sudo pip
```

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, `pip` and `python` are for Python 2; `pip3` and `python3` are for Python 3. Prefer Python 3 as most apps are finally getting away from Python 2.

Install Python apps in your $HOME folder, which persists across your GCP time/space continuum:

```
pip3 install --user <app>
```

Note you'll want to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable, discussed at length in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/46798, by adding the following to `~/.profile`:

```sh
# add local Python apps to PATH
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```